# Removing application titled "ThunderPenny"

Tags: html, iframe, static

I have tried to create a static HTML on my fan page using an application called [ThunderPenny](http://www.thunderpenny.com/).

The software was unsatisfactory and I tried to remove it and just use the Iframes application to accomplish what I was trying to accomplish.
I tried to remove thunderpenny from my page and all attempts are unsucessful.

- I hovered over the icon and clicked edit and remove from favorites and uninstall app.
- I close the editor and try to upload a new static html and when it loads up the static html reappears that I just removed.
- When I try to create a new one and try to edit to upload a website to the static html the thunderpenny page ops up again.

No matter what I try I cannot remove thunderpenny from trying to control the set up/ install process of a new static html.
I do not see a solution to this in the different Que's and do not know how to proceed, Please help.

Comment: I'm afraid to click that link.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your Page, click Edit Page > Update Page Info > More > Apps > Find the App you want to uninstall, click the X to the far right, then click Remove.